# Support plugin crashes every time

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

I am using **Android Studio 3.0.1**. And in this build, I found lot more issues than any previous version of it and it is very disgusting.

The big problem is crashing the **Android support plugin** every time. If I try to create a new activity using package->new -> and try to click any option then a crash will occur with a popup **IDE ERROR occurred**. And below given the messages and image.

**the comment section**

> Inconsistent FILE tree in
>   SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=LightVirtualFile:
>   \targetFile, content=VirtualFileContent{size=67}}; nodeLength=123;
>   fileLength=67

Detailed section

```
java.lang.Throwable
at com.intellij.util.ExceptionUtil.currentStackTrace(ExceptionUtil.java:65)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.currentStackTrace(DebugUtil.java:493)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaLogger.error(IdeaLogger.java:111)
at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.checkLengthConsistency(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:562)
at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.contentsSynchronized(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:207)
at com.intellij.pom.core.impl.PomModelImpl.commitTransaction(PomModelImpl.java:263)
at com.intellij.pom.core.impl.PomModelImpl.runTransaction(PomModelImpl.java:208)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.addInternal(XmlTagImpl.java:1095)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.addInternal(XmlTagImpl.java:1042)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.CompositePsiElement.addAfter(CompositePsiElement.java:163)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.addSubTag(XmlTagImpl.java:999)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.RecipeMergeUtils.mergeResourceFile(RecipeMergeUtils.java:255)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.RecipeMergeUtils.mergeXml(RecipeMergeUtils.java:145)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.DefaultRecipeExecutor.merge(DefaultRecipeExecutor.java:334)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe$MergeInstruction.execute(Recipe.java:215)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe.executeInstructions(Recipe.java:120)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe.execute(Recipe.java:110)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe.executeInstructions(Recipe.java:120)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe.execute(Recipe.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$4.process(Template.java:568)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils.processFreemarkerTemplate(FreemarkerUtils.java:102)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.executeRecipeFile(Template.java:557)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.access$200(Template.java:73)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$3.startElement(Template.java:519)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.processXml(Template.java:484)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.processFile(Template.java:468)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.lambda$doRender$2(Template.java:368)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$1.run(Template.java:347)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:171)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1023)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:170)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:210)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:149)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:119)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:168)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:151)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.runWriteCommandAction(Template.java:349)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.doRender(Template.java:367)
at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.render(Template.java:232)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.RenderTemplateModel$FreeMarkerTemplateRenderer.renderTemplate(RenderTemplateModel.java:267)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.RenderTemplateModel$FreeMarkerTemplateRenderer.doDryRun(RenderTemplateModel.java:196)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.MultiTemplateRenderer.countDown(MultiTemplateRenderer.java:58)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.MultiTemplateRenderer.requestRender(MultiTemplateRenderer.java:77)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.RenderTemplateModel.handleFinished(RenderTemplateModel.java:176)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:393)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:324)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:307)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1838)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:736)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:458)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1696)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1645)
at com.android.tools.idea.actions.NewAndroidComponentAction.actionPerformed(NewAndroidComponentAction.java:140)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:215)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:232)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:309)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:929)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:109)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:118)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Screen shot [image: Screen shot]

Note: Actually I am not getting any newly created resource or values. If I created any new id or resource, then I have to rebiuld to take effect. I don't know what is the real issue.

And I tried to disable plugin and it is unsuccessful beacuse I can't apply the changes If I disables the Android support plugin.

Any chance to avoid install new build?